# Most minimal Apache2 configuration for a python script that wgets, combines with local files and provides zip?

Tags: python, apache2

I have a PHP site setup on my server that also has `mod_wsgi` + Python 2.5 on it.

Occasionally I'm going to be asked to provide a zip of the entire site, and I'd like to use Python instead of PHP to do this.

What's the most minimal configuration I could make so that my python script is web accessible in order such that it can wget and grab static files of my site, add my media ( css, js ) directories to a zip and provide that zip to download?

Comment: Just realized another option would be setting up a php page that calls the command line and invokes the python script. I just don't want to deal with PHP to do the hard work and would prefer to do the zip stuff in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mod_wsgi site has very good documenation, [including a "QuickStart" guide](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide).  It comes complete with a very minimal python script to get you going.

If you want to use Python and go even simpler (and performace/load is not an issue), there's always the [cgi module](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html).

Comment: So I'd just need to setup my wget fetch, zipping in my application function and return a file attachment http headers, that's it?